# Fourier Transform on a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, fourier-transform

The question is quite simple: What would be the definition of Fourier Transform (and it's inverse) on a Riemannian Manifold?

I've found that a similar question has been asked at [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13902/does-a-fourier-transformation-on-a-pseudo-riemannian-manifold-make-sense) but that question was asking for a FT on a Lorentzian Manifold. The answer given is actually very good but then it gets a little too technical and quite cryptic to me...

The first comment on that question actually points at the right direction but could someone give me an example on a specific Riemannian Manifold (aside Euclidean), for example on a 2-cylinder with metric $g=dz^2+r^2d\theta^2$?

**PS:** Maybe I should have posted the question on Mathematics.SE but I was hopping for the physicists more direct approach to these kind of problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [Pontryagin duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) you find Fourier transforms on locally compact groups and you can translate the [Haar measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) over them so that (I think) in the Lie group case you obtain a Riemannian metric which evaluates on tangent vectors as the inner product of the Lie-algebra. E.g. as a smooth group $SU(2)$ has a Fourier transform by the duality and certainly a metric as $SU(2)∼\mathbb{S}^3⊂\mathbb{R}^4$.

In the Pontryagin case the key is to consider the group homomorphisms $\phi:G\rightarrow U(1)$ from your the group $G$ into the circle group. The maps $\phi$ translate the group operation in $G$ to the group operation in $U(1)$, which can be thought of the multiplication of phases. In the euclidean case $G=\mathbb{R}$, you have vectors $\vec x,\vec y\in \mathbb{R}$ and the group operation is the addition $\vec x+\vec y$. Then the functions $x\mapsto e^{i \vec p\vec x}$ (there is one such function for each $\vec p$) are the only homomorphisms: $e^{i \vec p\vec x}e^{i \vec p\vec y}=e^{i \vec p(\vec x+\vec y)}$ ($U(1)$ group operation on the left side, $G$ group operation on the right). This then relates to the the suitable function space $G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. The duality implies a representations of the functions $f(x)$ on $G$ involving an integral with the Haar measure and the homomorphism. In the case $G=\mathbb{R}$ you have $f(x)=\int g(p)e^{ipx}\text dp$ for some $g$. $x$- and $p$-space (translation- and phase-space) turn out to be $\mathbb{R}$.

The key is that on a Lie group you can translate stuff around and hence construct the $\phi$-maps. For any manifold without proper flow, this might be more difficult.

(Wait for other answers and comment though.)